# IntelliJ IDEA Maven project StackOverflowError when running debug configuration

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, stack-overflow

When I run mvn compile exec:exec, everything works fine, but when I click the debug button for the same configuration, it gives me the following error:

```
/home/miika/.jdks/openjdk-14.0.1/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/miika/IdeaProjects/jetfuel -Dmaven.home=/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3 -Dclassworlds.conf=/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.ext.class.path=/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven-event-listener.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds.license:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2020.1.2 compile exec:exec "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/lib/idea_rt.jar -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=40913,suspend=y,server=y -javaagent:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/java/lib/rt/debugger-agent.jar ${exec.args}"
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] ------------------------< com.discape:jetfuel >-------------------------
    [INFO] Building Jetfuel 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jetfuel ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 7 resources
    [INFO] Copying 0 resource
    [INFO] Copying 0 resource
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ jetfuel ---
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli) @ jetfuel ---
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  1.037 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-26T17:05:50+03:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------------------
    constituent[0]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/conf/logging/
    constituent[1]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
    constituent[2]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar
    constituent[3]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.4.1.jar
    constituent[4]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[5]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-core-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[6]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-compat-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[7]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.4.1.jar
    constituent[8]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.4.1.jar
    constituent[9]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
    constituent[10]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[11]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
    constituent[12]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[13]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
    constituent[14]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-http-3.3.4-shaded.jar
    constituent[15]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar
    constituent[16]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-builder-support-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[17]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
    constituent[18]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
    constituent[19]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.4.1.jar
    constituent[20]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-provider-api-3.3.4.jar
    constituent[21]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-api-1.4.1.jar
    constituent[22]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-util-1.4.1.jar
    constituent[23]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar
    constituent[24]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[25]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.29.jar
    constituent[26]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.4.jar
    constituent[27]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[28]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[29]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[30]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.29.jar
    constituent[31]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-file-3.3.4.jar
    constituent[32]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-embedder-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[33]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar
    constituent[34]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
    constituent[35]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.4.jar
    constituent[36]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar
    constituent[37]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-slf4j-provider-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[38]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/guava-25.1-android.jar
    constituent[39]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
    constituent[40]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar
    constituent[41]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-3.6.3.jar
    constituent[42]: file:/opt/IntelliJ-IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jansi-1.17.1.jar
    ---------------------------------------------------
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.stripTokens(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:453)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:160)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.java:428)
```

^ the end repeats for ~1020 lines

here's my pom.xml if anyone needs it:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/discapes/jetfuel/v1.1/pom.xml

I am trying to debug to find out which thread is preventing my application from closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made maven configuration `compile exec:exec "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044 com.me.myapp.myclass"`, and added remote configuration. Launched maven cfg, then remote cfg

Answer (score 2):

It is known issue, please vote for [IDEA-203018](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203018).

Answer (score 0):

I think you put the breakpoint on the method.Click to ctrl+shift+f8 list breakpoint,
and remove breakpoints on  methods